# Lost all file changes after reboot

Tags: raspbian, filesystem, readwrite

When I create any file, like `.bash_aliases` for example, and then I reboot using `sudo reboot`, all my changes are lost. 
I don't know if the card is read-only (I can actually create files).

I am running under Raspbian Jessie and I've been looking around for a solution. One I tried that did not work was to add a 'rw' before the waitreboot in `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

Does anybody have another idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you do as the top said and press enter when saving? I wasn't saving my file for a while until I learned how to do it.

Comment: What editor are you using to create the files?

Comment: I use nano, and I ctrl-x / Y to save and quit.  I have reinstalled Raspbian, I'll test tonight and report here after I've tried again!

Comment: I have same problem on all small file (seems to be a cache problem): all change are lost after reboot. I try different SD cards but same issue.
Very simple to test: change same lines in /boot/config.txt, save and reboot...
result: all change lost.

Comment: Anybody got a workaround for this?

Comment: same problem here!

Comment: The SD card is fried, you need a new one :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so according to [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=76351) it seems that can happen when the card gets corrupt.

Comment: Could you please include relevant information from the link in your answer, in case the link breaks in the future.

Comment: Well that's it really, the card is corrupt :) Just get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason when changes to the file system do not persist after reboot is the *[Overlay File System](https://pigeoncomputers.com/documentation/tips-and-tricks/overlay-file-system/)* option is enabled. I accidentally enabled that option, and after disabling it via

```
sudo raspi-config
```

**4 Performance Options** > **P3 Overlay File System** > **No**

changes to the files system were stored to the SD card again.